# Different rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have already this rewrite rule in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?id_user=$1&page=$2 [L]

http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?id_user=user&page=news
http://www.mydomain.com/user/news.html
```

Now i have a problem for news details and event details.

for have an url like this (only for page news):

```
http://www.mydomain.com/user/details-news/category/title-news.html
```

and this  (only for page event)

```
http://www.mydomain.com/user/event/title-event.html
```

Can i insert new rule in htaccess for have these rules or i must edit my actually rules?

My url is the same for all query

```
index.php?id_user=user&page=details-news&category=category&title=title-news
or
index.php?id_user=user&page=event&title=title-event
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You actual rule match only against:

```
^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$
```

urls.

Which means only one / inside. So you can add other rules with more slash, without the need to modify this actual existing rule.

The only problem would be if you want to add other rules with one /. But this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
# skip further rules for files/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /index.php?id_user=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /index.php?id_user=$1&page=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /index.php?id_user=$1&page=$2&category=$3&title=$4 [L,QSA]
```